# UIView Slide Transition,in view based Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using slide transition,

by using this code,

```
        Home *lisnx = [[Home alloc] init];
        CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        [self presentModalViewController:lisnx animated:NO];
        [animation setDuration:0.40];
        [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
        [[lisnx.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];
        [lisnx release];
```

but in landscape mode when i move from one view to another view every thing shifted right
 for landscape i have used this code,

```
        self.view.bounds=CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,480.0,320.0);
        scroll.frame=CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,480.0,320.0);
        bgImg.frame=CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,480.0,320.0);
```

How to way out from this problem please some body help me.

Comment: format your code :) it's hard to read otherwise

Answer (score 0):

you need to give different frame to each view, for Portrait as well Landscape.

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    scroll.frame=CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,480.0,320.0); 
    ...            
 } 
else {

 scroll.frame=CGRectMake(0.0,200.0,200.0,320.0);
 ...
}
```

give your frame here,